# Certificate pinning with Alamofire using an installed Profile

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire, certificate-pinning

I am using Alamofire to make web requests. There is a requirement to use certificate pinning for more security. So far I am able to pin certificates which are already included in the bundle using the following code.

```
let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
        certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
)
let serverTrustPolicies = [domain: serverTrustPolicy]
let sessionManager = SessionManager(
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
```

But also there's another requirement to use the certificate from Keychain which is installed under "General -> Profiles & Device Management". I tried different ways to access the installed profile. But no luck. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance